# Plot DataFrame row by row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrameGroupBy that is relatively small. Below is my whole data per day. Albeit there going to be a few years worth of days.

```
            day loc_source loc_target  count
0  1.566691e+09       east       east   1768
1  1.566691e+09       east       west    559
2  1.566691e+09    unknown       east     73
3  1.566691e+09    unknown       west    160
4  1.566691e+09       west       east     53
5  1.566691e+09       west       west   1563
```

Now I want to plot this: `count` vs. `day`, one line for each unique combination of `loc_source` and `loc_target`. 6 lines in total. 1 plot.

I can do this by iterating over the rows, but I do not believe this is the right way to do it. How can I plot this in matplotlib?

Edit: I cannot add the expected output, since it's a plot. But I can describe it: The plot should show numbers from 0 to 2000 on the y axis (label count), and a single datapoint on the x axis (`1.55591e+09`) (for now, of course this is going to change once I use the full dataset). There are 6 lines on the plot:

```
LEGEND       y VALUE
east east       1768
east west        559
unknown east      73
unknown west     160
west east         53
west west       1563
```

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: @QuangHoang See my edit.

Comment: `df.groupby(['loc_source', 'loc_target']).plot(x='day', y='count', ax=ax)` where `ax` is an axes object, e.g. `_, ax = plt.subplots()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot` to restructure your data first. First we create a new column with the east/west values:

`df['eastwest'] = df['loc_source'] + df['loc_target']`

Then we restructure your data and plot:

`df.pivot(index='day', columns='eastwest', values='count').plot()`

This moves the day into the index and creates columns for each combination of loc_source and loc_target. Calling plot will create a line per column where the day will be on the x axis and count on the y axis.